# How to assign a shortcut for Eclipse View like Console?

Tags: eclipse

I have several 'views' that i usually focus on. Because of my small screen, i usually have **1 view maximized**.

Switching between views is a nuisance, as i have to restore maximize, click on '*console view*', and then maximize again. Or click to '*junit view*', to re-rerun the test or maximize the '*junit stacktrace tab*'.

I wonder if i could have assigned each of my frequently used views with a shortcut of my own and thus **avoid restoring, clicking, double clicking**, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open Console, you can click Alt + Shift + Q and then Click C or you can also enable auto pop Console up when building in options. To switch perspectives by shortcut you have to change key binding. If you want to change keybindings Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys and type **perspective** in search window.

Comment: This is great ! Do you happen to know how to focus on 'JUnit' tab beside 'Package Explorer' tab with a shortcut ?

Comment: Do you mean, when you press your shortcut for open view that include both of them JUnit and Package Explorer then you want to JUnit on Top and Package Explorer in other tab?

Comment: Maybe do you want to try binds with **Show view** @bertie? I'm C/C++ dev and a lot of features can be bind in this window you should try with JUnit. Good luck!